# Replace words in between single quotes

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to replace the words between single quotes in a fil in bash, i tried with sed but its not working.

**File contents**

```
Haarlem -m 'foo' -n 'bar' aalsmeer > "goes to" -t 'value'
Roterdam -m 'foo2' -n 'bar2' amsterdam > "goes to" -t 'value'
```

**expected output**

```
Haarlem -m "verified" -n "verified" aalsmeer > "goes to" -t 'value'
Roterdam -m "verified" -n "verified" amsterdam > "goes to" -t 'value'
```

my below sed command is not working

```
sed 's/-m '*.*' -n '*.*'/-m "verified" -n "verified"/'
```

Comment: Your regex is wrong - `*` is not a wildcard in regex, but a quantifier.

Comment: You also have a problem with the single quotes around the `sed` command interfering with those in the regular expression you are using to match the string to be replaced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use double quotes here:

```
$ sed "s/'[^']*'/\"verified\"/g" ip.txt
Haarlem -m "verified" -n "verified" aalsmeer > "goes to"
Roterdam -m "verified" -n "verified" amsterdam > "goes to"
```

- `'[^']*'` matches `'` followed by non `'` characters and again `'` character

  - you cannot use `'.*'` because that will match from first `'` to last `'` in the input line
- `\"verified\"` use `"verified"` as replacement string, double quote is escaped because it is being used inside double quotes

See also: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes and [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y) (for difference between regex and wildcards)

The question was updated after above solution.

```
$ cat ip.txt
Haarlem -m 'foo' -n 'bar' aalsmeer > "goes to" -t 'value'
Roterdam -m 'foo2' -n 'bar2' amsterdam > "goes to" -t 'value'

$ sed -E "s/(-[mn] )'[^']*'/\1\"verified\"/g" ip.txt
Haarlem -m "verified" -n "verified" aalsmeer > "goes to" -t 'value'
Roterdam -m "verified" -n "verified" amsterdam > "goes to" -t 'value'
```

- `-[mn]` will match either `-m` or `-n`
- `(-[mn] )` is a capture group, the content matched is reused in replacement section as `\1`

You can also use

```
sed -E "s/(-[^t] )'[^']*'/\1\"verified\"/g" ip.txt
```

to prevent only `-t '..'` from getting replaced and match all other single quoted patterns preceded by `-<char>` and a space

Comment: I have added last part now -t par(which should be unchanged value), could u please check.

Comment: @ajay in future try to avoid changing the question and add all the details from the start itself.. I have updated the answer

Comment: @Sandeep - noted. just started using this forum, will make a note of it.

Comment: @ajay sure no problem, also I wish to clarify that editing the question to add more details is perfectly okay.. but in this case the problem statement itself changed, which is what you could try to avoid in future...

Comment: @Sandeep - Yes got the point, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I applaud the answer from Sundeep, but depending on how much you trust your data you can do it much simpler.

You only want to look at the first two occurrences thus you can simply call the same command twice. I choose the non-whitespace character assuming you have a whole word/numbers between quotes. The `-E` is just to be able to do extended regular expression.

test_file

```
Haarlem -m 'foo' -n 'bar' aalsmeer > "goes to"
Roterdam -m 'foo2' -n 'bar2' amsterdam > "goes to"
```

```
$ sed -E \
  -e "s/'\S+'/\"verified\"/" \
  -e "s/'\S+'/\"verifired\"/" test_file
#  
# Haarlem -m "verified" -n "verifired" aalsmeer > "goes to" -t 'value'
# Roterdam -m "verified" -n "verifired" amsterdam > "goes to" -t 'value'
```